# Is it ok for me to ask for money/gift card instead of a package for Christmas?

Tags: professionalism, netherlands

I live in The Netherlands, so I'm not sure if the same practice is also in the US (or other countries). But here, generally around Christmas time, it's typical for the employer to give Christmas packages as a "gift" to employees for Christmas. That's fine, but the packages I've got from this employer the last 2 years contain items that 9 times out of 10 I don't need/want, and I give them away to my friends.. now I'm not at a high income atm, I was wondering if it is OK for me to ask my employer to, instead of giving me a Christmas package, give me the value in cash, or a gift card, that I can select items that I need? Would that be too rude to do? (After all, he doesn't *have* to give us a Christmas package).. Or would it be reasonable (my income is below minimum wage)?

Comment: If your income is below minimum wage, you might ask yourself if it is reasonable to work there at all.

Comment: @Brandin my income is below minimum wage, but that is because I can't work fulltime yet.. my income per hour is semi-reasonable I think

Comment: I don't think anyone can answer this without knowing your company's culture. I would point out that the company may be getting gifts at a discount, so the case equivalent may be less than you expect.

Comment: Im in the US and I wouldn't think that is appropriate. At some companies I've worked for, we voted for what the company would give us, and at another we either got something or we didn't. I would feel that if you asked for money instead, it would seem like you don't appreciate their gesture of kindness. But again, it would depend on your company culture there. On another note, you could always try to sell the things they give you, just try not to let any co-workers know about it. Politics and all.

Comment: @keshlam what do you need to know about my company's culture? (at)Michael Pickett, I feel really bad about it too, but it boils down to the point that I have to "give away" things that I would/could have otherwise used, and being on the low end of things (less than minimal income).. these are just household things, don't think I can sell them, just things like "1 jar of paté" and things like that

Comment: Not a proper answer, but if the company has enough employees, they will be geting this Christmas presents at huge discounts, so what you could get in cash would be far less than the value of the gifts. If you can't sell them, you could try swapping with friends. And just to actually answer your question, asking for the cash would be extremely rude in Spain.

Comment: My point is that the answer may differ from company to company, so your best approach would be to enquire there rather than asking us. Our answers may not apply to you.

Comment: Depends on your country, but this could be a tax headache. A small seasonal gift (eg bottle of wine) may be counted as "trivial" for tax reasons, and not require your employer to cover your tax obligation for its value. This is unlikely to be true for a small gift of cash.

Comment: @AJ_ what I did with my useless Christmas gifts was giving them away or swapping them on facebook groups for something else

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not appropriate to stipulate what you want as a gift of this sort. If you get an Xmas bonus that is a totally different scenario. But a gift is totally up to the giver and should be accepted (good or bad) in the spirit in which it is given.

You can always ask, but it's not the 'right' thing to do.

I get lots of things that are useless to me, mostly alcohol (I don't drink), but I thank the giver respectfully and keep any disappointment to myself.

Comment: I hadn't thought of it this way.. thanks for the feedback

Comment: Also note that things that are useless to you can be used as gifts, offerings or products to sell to others.

Answer (score 1):

It is extremely rude to refuse or express distaste with a gift that is given in good faith and is not a dishonor to you.

With any honest gift, the thing to do is to make the best use of it that you can.

If the gift is trashy, thoughtless or is a "joke" gift, then just privately throw it away.